# Cannot dequeue UICollectionReusableView from storyboard prototype

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that uses a custom `UICollectionReusableView`. I'm trying to dequeue this view (NPClipDisclosedView) from the prototype view that I setup inside my collection view in the storyboard.

If I call `-registerClass: forSupplementaryViewOfKind: withReuseIdentifier`, it properly dequeues the view, but the UI elements I added in the prototype view are not there. I'd rather not create all the UI by code, hence this problem.

The exact crash occurs here when dequeue is called:

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)inCollectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)inKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)inIndexPath
{

    NPClipDisclosedView *supplementaryView = nil;
    supplementaryView = [inCollectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:inKind withReuseIdentifier:NPClipDisclosedViewIdentifier forIndexPath:inIndexPath];


    return supplementaryView;
}
```

Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionView.m:3241
2014-05-29 18:24:07.442 APPNAME[39671:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: NPClipDisclosedViewKind with identifier NPClipDisclosedViewIdentifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:

The assertion message says that I can connect a prototype cell in the storyboard. Well, it's set up inside my collection view, just like my reusable cell. So why is it not finding my reusable view? Is it literally only for *cells*, not reusable views?

I can alternatively register a nib but I would like to use the prototype view in my storyboard.

Comment: The code you posted should work, at least for a collection view in a UIViewController (which is what I've done in the past). Have you made sure that NPClipDisclosedView is a subclass of UICollectionReusableView, and that your identifier in the storyboard is the same as what you're passing to the dequeue method?

Comment: Yes, I did check those. One thing I noticed is as I add my UICollectionReusableView to the collection view in storyboard, the collection view automatically marks it as either header or footer depending on where I put it. Maybe that's why it's not finding it.. but If I uncheck it, the view is removed.